# Oracle SQL - Fiscal Week of Year

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to calculate the Fiscal Week of the Year with the following rules:

- The fiscal year always starts on June/01
- The week always starts on Sunday
- Samples are provided for 2019 but ideally it should work for any year

A few samples of correct values are provided with the screenshot attached

I tried to do something like TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(DATE_ID + 1,'DD-Mon-YY'),'IW')) -21 but towards the end of the Calendar year I start to get negatives

```
SELECT
    DATE_ID
    , WEEK_OF_YEAR
FROM DATE_DIM
WHERE
    DATE_ID IN
    (
        20190601
        , 20190602
        , 20190915
        , 20191228
        , 20191229
        , 20200101
        , 20200601
        , 20200606
        , 20200607
    )
ORDER BY DATE_ID ASC
;
```

[image: Values in the screenshot hardcoded for illustration purpose]

Comment: So, 2019-06-01 is by definition in the first week of the fiscal year. And as it is a Saturday, 2019-05-27 to 2019-05-31 are also in the first week of that fiscal year, because a week stars with the Sunday. And 2019-06-02, another Sunday, starts the second fiscal week. Correct?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner for 2019-06-01, that would be the only day of the first fiscal week, since the criteria is that every fiscal year starts on that day no matter what. 2019-05-26 is Sunday and would be the first day of a fiscal Year but from the previous fiscal year. 2019-06-02 as you correctly point out is another Sunday starts the second fiscal week

Comment: I see now, you don't have a date, but a column you call date_id which is a string or number holding a date in the format 'YYYYMMDD'. Correct? Then you have `TO_DATE(date_id + 1, 'DD-Mon-YY')`, which means you take that date number and add one (e.g. 20000101 -> 20000102, but also 20001231 -> 20001232 which is an invalid date). Why then the format `'DD-Mon-YY'`??? Your string would have to look like '31-Dec-00' instead of '20001231' for this to work. This looks completely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,+7),'IW')
  FROM dual
```

Or in your case,

```
SELECT date_id,TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE(date_id,'YYYYMMDD'),+7),'IW') week_of_year
  FROM date_dim
```

If you don't like the ISO dating where week 1 is the week beginning Sunday during which the 1st of the year falls, you can try offsetting it by moving it back to the previous sunday (TRUNC(..,'D'), then advance a week, then add the 7 months. See if this works for you:

```
SELECT date_id, TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(date_id,'D') + 7,7),'IW') week_of_year
  FROM date_dim
```

Comment: I tried to add the code but unfortunately none of the values match, the reference value of 20190601 gives me that is the week 48, when it should be the 1st week of the fiscal year

Comment: Corrected... June to Jan is 7 months, not 6.

Comment: I tried the updated code and gives some correct values. 2019-06-01 is correctly classified as week #1, but 2019-06-02 which is a Sunday it should be the first day of week #2, it gets classified as #1

Comment: It soundsl ike you don't want to use the ISO definition of week numbers, but your own where week 1 always follows the 1st of the year rather than immediately precedes it?

Comment: I tried to solve the problem using the ISO definition but it didn't work, so maybe it is something custom that is required based on the criteria that I posted in the question. I'm not sure how to solve it at this point. The important thing is that the fiscal year always starts on June-01, that is what defines the week #1, and the other criteria is that Sunday is always the first day of the fiscal week.

Comment: I tried all the update queries, I would say 95% of the values are correct, however a few of them get classified incorrectly, for example June/05/2025 it gets classified as fiscal week #2, when it's part of week #1. June/01/2025 is Sunday, so it's the beginning of the week and also the beginning of the fiscal year

Comment: I think you have enough to go on... it's trial and error tweaking from here.

Comment: @IsaacB - Just posted the Updated Answer - please check it out...

Answer (score 0):

You got confused with your date formats ('yyyymmdd' vs. 'DD-Mon-YY'), so I am using a real date (mydate) in my answer. Convert your string or number to a proper date and you are there :-)

The important thing is to check whether your date is >= June 1. Once this is done you can subtract that year's June 1 or the previous year's one. Well, more or less :-)

```
select 
  mydate,
  to_char(mydate, 'DY') as tag,
  trunc
  (
    case when to_char(mydate, 'mmdd') >= '0601' then
      trunc(mydate + 1, 'iw') + 6 - to_date(to_char(mydate, 'yyyy') || '0601', 'yyyymmdd')
    else
      trunc(mydate + 1, 'iw') + 6 - to_date(to_char(extract(year from mydate) - 1) || '0601', 'yyyymmdd')
    end / 7
  ) + 1 as fiscal_week
from ...
order by mydate;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/N5pX_5cV

Answer (score 0):

***UPDATED ANSWER***
You can try this - provide the date like 31-MAY-19 to start your calendar from 01-JUN-19 and define how many days you want. There is a shift of 5 months as the code was taken from my regular calendar and adjusted the start of week to sunday...Tested OK for periods up to 2 years per run. So if you want 6 years you'll have to run this 3 times...

```sql
WITH 
        base_calendar AS
            (
                SELECT CurrDate         AS Day_ID,
                TO_CHAR(CurrDate,'Day') AS Week_Day_Full,
                TO_CHAR(CurrDate,'DY')  AS Week_Day_Short,
                TO_NUMBER(TRIM(leading '0' FROM TO_CHAR(CurrDate,'D'))) AS Day_Num_of_Week,
                --
                MAX(CASE WHEN To_Char(CurrDate, 'ddmm') = '2902' THEN EXTRACT(YEAR From CurrDate) END) OVER(Order By CurrDate Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row) AS last_leap_year,
                Count(CASE WHEN (   TO_CHAR(CurrDate,'DY') = 'SUN' And 
                                    CurrDate Between To_date('01.06.' || To_Char(EXTRACT(YEAR From CurrDate)), 'dd.mm.yyyy') And To_date('31.05.' || To_Char(EXTRACT(YEAR From CurrDate) + 1), 'dd.mm.yyyy')  )
                                OR
                                 (   TO_CHAR(CurrDate,'DY') = 'SUN' And 
                                    CurrDate Between To_date('01.06.' || To_Char(EXTRACT(YEAR From CurrDate) - 1), 'dd.mm.yyyy') And To_date('31.05.' || To_Char(EXTRACT(YEAR From CurrDate)  ), 'dd.mm.yyyy')  )
                          THEN 1 
                      END) OVER(Order By CurrDate Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row) AS cnt_sundays
              FROM
                (
                    SELECT level n,
                        -- Calendar starts at the day after this date
                        TO_DATE('31/05/2019','DD/MM/YYYY') + NUMTODSINTERVAL(level,'DAY') CurrDate
                    FROM dual
                        -- Change for the number of days to be added to the table.
                    CONNECT BY level <= 731
                )
            )
SELECT  DISTINCT
      day_id,
      CASE  WHEN  (cnt_sundays + 1 ) - ( (EXTRACT(YEAR From Add_Months(Day_id, - 5)) -EXTRACT(YEAR From MIN(Day_id) OVER()) ) * 53) >= 54 THEN 1
            WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR From day_id) <> last_leap_year And day_id > = To_Date('01.06.' || To_Char(EXTRACT(YEAR From day_id)), 'dd.mm.yyyy' ) 
                THEN (cnt_sundays + 1)  - ( (EXTRACT(YEAR From Add_Months(Day_id, - 5)) -EXTRACT(YEAR From MIN(Day_id) OVER()) ) * 53) + 1
      ELSE (cnt_sundays + 1) - ( (EXTRACT(YEAR From Add_Months(Day_id, - 5)) -EXTRACT(YEAR From MIN(Day_id) OVER()) ) * 53) 
      END week_of_year,
      --
        week_day_full,
        week_day_short,
        CASE week_day_short   
            WHEN 'SUN' THEN 1
            WHEN 'MON' THEN 2
            WHEN 'TUE' THEN 3
            WHEN 'WED' THEN 4
            WHEN 'THU' THEN 5
            WHEN 'FRI' THEN 6
            WHEN 'SAT' THEN 7
    END AS day_num_of_week
FROM base_calendar
ORDER BY day_id
```

R E S U L T S :

```sql
DAY_ID    WEEK_OF_YEAR WEEK_DAY_FULL WEEK_DAY_SHORT DAY_NUM_OF_WEEK
--------- ------------ ------------- -------------- ---------------
01-JUN-19            1 Saturday      SAT                          7 
02-JUN-19            2 Sunday        SUN                          1 
03-JUN-19            2 Monday        MON                          2 
04-JUN-19            2 Tuesday       TUE                          3 
05-JUN-19            2 Wednesday     WED                          4
... ...
... ...
13-SEP-19           16 Friday        FRI                          6 
14-SEP-19           16 Saturday      SAT                          7 
15-SEP-19           17 Sunday        SUN                          1 
16-SEP-19           17 Monday        MON                          2
... ...
30-DEC-19           32 Monday        MON                          2 
31-DEC-19           32 Tuesday       TUE                          3 
01-JAN-20           32 Wednesday     WED                          4 
02-JAN-20           32 Thursday      THU                          5 
...
27-FEB-20           40 Thursday      THU                          5 
28-FEB-20           40 Friday        FRI                          6 
29-FEB-20           40 Saturday      SAT                          7 
01-MAR-20           41 Sunday        SUN                          1 
02-MAR-20           41 Monday        MON                          2
...
29-MAY-20           53 Friday        FRI                          6 
30-MAY-20           53 Saturday      SAT                          7 
31-MAY-20            1 Sunday        SUN                          1 
01-JUN-20            1 Monday        MON                          2 
02-JUN-20            1 Tuesday       TUE                          3 
03-JUN-20            1 Wednesday     WED                          4 
04-JUN-20            1 Thursday      THU                          5 
05-JUN-20            1 Friday        FRI                          6 
06-JUN-20            1 Saturday      SAT                          7 
07-JUN-20            2 Sunday        SUN                          1
...  ...
...  ...
22-MAY-21           51 Saturday      SAT                          7 
23-MAY-21           52 Sunday        SUN                          1 
24-MAY-21           52 Monday        MON                          2 
25-MAY-21           52 Tuesday       TUE                          3 
26-MAY-21           52 Wednesday     WED                          4 
27-MAY-21           52 Thursday      THU                          5 
28-MAY-21           52 Friday        FRI                          6 
29-MAY-21           52 Saturday      SAT                          7 
30-MAY-21           53 Sunday        SUN                          1 
31-MAY-21           53 Monday        MON                          2 

 731 rows selected
```

... with year 2025 - part of the result mentioned in comments above ...

```sql
... ...
29-MAY-25           53 Thursday      THU                          5 
30-MAY-25           53 Friday        FRI                          6 
31-MAY-25           53 Saturday      SAT                          7 
01-JUN-25            1 Sunday        SUN                          1 
02-JUN-25            1 Monday        MON                          2 
03-JUN-25            1 Tuesday       TUE                          3 
04-JUN-25            1 Wednesday     WED                          4 
05-JUN-25            1 Thursday      THU                          5 
06-JUN-25            1 Friday        FRI                          6 
07-JUN-25            1 Saturday      SAT                          7 
08-JUN-25            2 Sunday        SUN                          1 
... ...
```